# What's the difference between public method and abstract method in Interface?

Tags: java, interface

Consider the following interface :

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public void func1();
    public void func2();
    abstract public void func3();

}
```

and the class MyClass :

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface{

    @Override
    public void func1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void func2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void func3() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

What's the difference between `func2()` and `func3()` ?

I must implement both when I want to implement `MyClass` , so it seems that there's no
difference if I write `public` or `abstract public` in the interface .

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Java 7 and earlier:**

There is no difference since all interface methods are public and "abstract." This is implied whether declared or not.

**Java 8:**

The same rules apply as in Java 7, however, it should be noted that since Java 8, only non-default methods are "abstract." [Default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), are in fact, allowed to have an implementation.

**Java 9:**

In Java 9, we are provided even more flexibility, and also allowed to have [private methods](https://www.journaldev.com/12850/java-9-private-methods-interfaces).

Answer (score 7):

[Java Language Specification quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> **Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract**, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a
>   block.

You ask

> What's the difference between func2() and func3() ?

Except for the fact that they are different methods, their modifiers are the same.

Answer (score 2):

What's the difference between public method and abstract method in Interface?

[9.1.1.1. abstract Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1)
Simply said... none. According to this, it's obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, we are comparing apples and oranges in this question. For someone new to the Java language, some clarifications need to be made first:

**Interfaces:**

- Interfaces contain method stubs. These are methods *without* a body. 
  These methods are implicitly "abstract" and we do not need to explicitly use a modifier to denote this.
- That being said, *since* **Java 8**, we now have what are called "[default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)." These methods are fully implemented methods which do require an explicit declaration using the `default` keyword.
- That being said, the `abstract` keyword never comes into play in the context of an interface.

**Abstract Methods:**

- Abstract methods *only* belong in abstract classes.
- An abstract class may contain fully implemented methods along with abstract methods. However, just one abstract method in a class is enough to make it an abstract class - That is, the class *must* be explicitly declared as an abstract class.

Answer (score -1):

An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

Comment: I didn't refer to abstract class , but for an interface with an abstract method .